# react-select multi select component bug

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

I am having difficulty using react-select with the isMulti prop. Even though it is meant to be a multi-select component, when I choose an option, react-select indicates that there are no other options available.

example:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-typescript-forked-67hdk7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I know that it has something to do with js map function but i can't figure out on my own.

example:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-typescript-forked-67hdk7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because all your options have the same value (in your case the same price).

Make sure to assign a unique `value` to each option of a select (typically an ID).